How to Increase plot generation speed with Matplotlib?
I'm using Matplotlib to generate images of trajectories from videos, but it's very slow—around 0.05s to 0.1s per trajectory. A single frame can contain 4 to 5 trajectories, so I'm looking for alternatives or ways to increase the generation speed.
Here's the function I use:
def generate_img(video_id,track_history,trajectory_min,trajectory_max):
    for trajectoryId, traj in track_history.items():
        xlimMax, ylimMax, xlimMin, ylimMin = findMinMaxXY(track_history=track_history, trackID=trajectoryId)
        if len(traj) < trajectory_min:
            continue
        if len(traj) >= trajectory_max:
            traj.pop(0)
        traj.pop(0)
        traj = np.array(traj)
        
        # Plot trajectories using matplotlib
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))
        ax.set_xlim(xlimMin, xlimMax)
        ax.set_ylim(ylimMin, ylimMax)
        ax.axis('off')

        ax.plot(traj[:, 0], traj[:, 1], linewidth=8)

        os.makedirs(f'trajectory_image/{video_id}/', exist_ok=True)
        fig.savefig(f'trajectory_image/{video_id}/{trajectoryId}.png', bbox_inches='tight')
        plt.close('all')

I've tried VisPy, but the drawing seems misaligned. PyQtGraph gives an error: 'QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget.
